# Connecting to Admin secured webservice on App Engine from Java client

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine, authentication, oauth

I've got a simple Java tool that I use for calling webservices on App Engine to help me with maintenance and management. I currently secure the pages by only allowing admin access using the web.xml file and

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>xxxxxx</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/xxxxxx</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Which is fine when making calls from a browser as it goes through the authentication process, but if I want to access the page using a Java client what should my approach be?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, each of your requests must contain credentials that allow it to be executed. All requests without such credentials are rejected.

In the most simple form, you can include a client-secret - a long random string that is very hard to guess - with your requests. Your code will include this secret, while requests from outside won't know to include it.

For a more secure/robust implementation you may look at an [existing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10296681/is-there-an-oauth-2-0-provider-implementation-in-java-not-oauth-client), but it may be too much for a simple tool.

Comment: I was hoping to validate a token against an admin account server side so that other developers with access to client code can't accidentally or intentionally mess around with the server settings. I'm guessing I need to go down the OAuth route for that, but I can't work out where to start.

Comment: It depends on your use case - how many outside developers you expect and how secure it has to be. I use a few web services where they give me a client secret and nothing else, and I simply include it with all requests. If you do want something very robust and secure, follow the link which I included - it lists a number of existing libraries you may consider.

Comment: Here is another link with an example: http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/java/example/oauth-provider/

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look. I might just go the client secret for now as that's nice and easy. I could always get it to ask me to input a password too for an added layer of security. No need to over engineer (yet).